SARIMA - 1 day gap between prediction vs observed data after removing seasonality
I need to identify outliers in my data, ranging from 2023-01-01 to 2024-08-31. My data is stationary and has seasonality of 7 days. I've decided to use the SARIMA model, by using SARIMAX in Python to fit my model.
In order to have a more robust approach to identifying outliers, I've decided to fit my data in 2 ways:

Use the original data, with seasonality, and have a seasonal component of 7 in my SARIMA model.
Remove the seasonality of my data, and fit the model using SARIMAX but with seasonal_component = (0,0,0,0).

I've written the code for that already. The prediction for the original data is fitting well. However, my attempt at fitting the data without seasonality, for the whole dataframe, the prediction seems to be ahead by 1 day. i.e, if I shift the in_sample_summary by -1, it fits well with my observed data for the whole period.
Even though shifting the in_sample_summary by -1 seems to align the prediction to the observed values, I wanted to understand why that is happening. In order to remove seasonality, I did without_seasonality['seasonal_diff'] = without_seasonality[measure] - without_seasonality[measure].shift(7)
My questions is:

Why is there 1 day gap when I fit my model after removing the seasonality?

Any help is more than welcomed!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

hello there could u give me the link to your dataset to reproduce the same thing that u are trying to achieve

Sure thing!  Here is the link
